# MySQL update statement that partially changes the value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to update the value of a column in a db table substituting part of a path.

My current path is:

```
software-features/adadadad.html
```

It should become:

```
software/adadadad.html
```

I need an sql update statement (valid for MySQL 5.5) that changes just a part of the value of a column

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include what you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
    set path = replace(path, 'software-features', 'software')
    where path like 'software-features%';
```

Answer (score 1):

The "replace" function would seem to do what you want, but it's unclear from your question how specific or generalized the solution you're looking for is:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
   SET path = REPLACE(path, "software-features/", "software/")
```